# Showing that a subgroup generated by two elements has order $p^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have the following exercise:

Let $p$ be a prime. Let $G$ be a group of order $p^3$, generated by three elements $x, y, z$ each with order $p$ which satisfies the following relations
$$yz=zy, \qquad xz=zx, \qquad yx=xyz$$
Supposs that $N=<y,z>$. Show that $N$ has order $p^2$. It's easy to narrow it down to $N$ having order $p$ or $p^2$, but how do I show it is not $p$?

Comment: Clearly, $\langle y\rangle$ has order $p$, so if you show $z\notin \langle y\rangle$, and $x\notin\langle y,z\rangle$, you are done.

Comment: Yes, but how do I show that $z \notin <y>$ using the relations?

Comment: By definition wouldn't  "generated by three elements" mean $z \ne y^k $ for any integer $k $?  Is $p $ supposed to be prime?

Comment: Yes, it is prime. I'm not so sure about assuming that $z \neq y^k$. I think it's possible to show it even without assuming this.

Comment: I think I got it. Let's show that $N$ has more than $p$ elements, and hence $p^2$. The elements in $<z>$ are obviously also elements in $N$. Hence there are at least $p$ elements. Let's show that $y \neq z^k$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Assuming $y=z^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $z^k x=xz^{k+1}$. Hence by using that $z$ and $k$ commute, we have $x z^k =xz^{k+1}$. By cancellation we have would have $z=1$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the relations $yz = zy, xz = zx$ and $G = \langle x, y, z \rangle$, we can see that $z$ is central. On the other hand, $[y, x] = y^{-1}x^{-1}yx = z \neq 1$ by the relation $yx = xyz$ and the hypothesis $z$ has order $p$. Thus, $y$ is not central and $y \notin \langle z \rangle$ in particular. Therefore, we have $\lvert \langle y, z \rangle \rvert \neq p$.